# How to make a Range with .., but counting down

Tags: raku

I want to have a loop that counts from 5 to 1. I know I can do the opposite easily with the `..` operator:

```
for 1..5 { .print }
12345
```

But when using the `..` operator and reversing the sides, it doesn't seem to generate a valid Range that `for` can work with:

```
for 5..1 { .print }
Nil
```

I know I can use the `reverse` method on the Range object:

```
for (1..5).reverse { .print }
54321
```

However, I would expect that the `..` operator has a certain way to generate the list of numbers in 1 call. My question is, how to create a Range that counts down using the `..` operator?

Comment: You can also make more general sequences with [`...`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_...), including `5...1`.  Not as efficient as Range .reverse I believe.

Comment: Looks like I will be optimizing that in the same way I just did `^10 .reverse` tomorrow.  That would make it about 75x faster :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `5...1` (note the 3 `...` ):

```
for 5...1 { .print }
54321
```

The iterator that `Range.reverse` is basically the same iterator as for forwards, but iterating from the end to the beginning.  Apart from the extra initial call to `.reverse`, there should be no difference in execution.

Except for the fact that `for 1..5 { }` is actually statically optimized to not use a `Range` internally at all.  I guess this is an opportunity for a further statical optimization.

EDIT: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/2dd02751da ensures that `for (1..5).reverse` is optimized in the same way as `for 1..5`.  This makes it about 6x faster.

EDIT: As of https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/dfd6450d74 , the best way to count down a Range is `for 5...1`: this uses the same optimization as `(1..5).reverse`, but is much more readable.